# fs.writeFile() está sobrescrevendo um arquivo

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Estou escrevendo um script usando Node.JS que verifica quantos pontos um cliente tem no cadastro dele, e eu preciso que a cada compra acima de 150 reais que ele faça, o ponto aumente em 1, quando chegar em 10, o cliente tem um desconto automático de 25%

Preciso que sobrescrever uma informação em um arquivo .json, mas quando chamo a função fs.writeFile(), ela sobrescreve o arquivo inteiro

meu código:

```
const data = fs.readFileSync('test.json', 'utf8')
var document = JSON.parse(data)

command(client, 'test_pay', (message) => {  
    var cont = message.content.replace('%test_pay', '').split(' ')
    var value = cont[0]
    var clientId = cont[1] - 1
    var clientScore = 9 //document.clients[clientId].score
    var client = document.clients[clientId].nome
    var valueOff = value - ((value * 25) / 100)

    if (value >= 150) {
        clientScore += 1;
        var data = JSON.stringify(clientScore, null, 2)
        fs.writeFile('test.json', data, finished)
        function finished(err) {
            console.log('all set.')
        }
        console.log("=====================")
        console.log(`Mensagem: ${message.content}`)
        console.log(`Valor: ${value}`)
        console.log(`Id do Cliente: ${clientId}`)
        console.log("=====================")
        console.log(`Cliente: ${client}`)
        console.log(`Valor pago: R$${value}`)
        console.log(`Score: ${clientScore}`)
        console.log("=====================")
        console.log()
    } else {
        console.log("=====================")
        console.log(`Mensagem: ${message.content}`)
        console.log(`Valor: ${value}`)
        console.log(`Id do Cliente: ${clientId}`)
        console.log("=====================")
        console.log(`Cliente: ${client}`)
        console.log(`Valor pago: R$${value}`)
        console.log(`Score: ${clientScore}`)
        console.log("=====================")
        console.log()
    }

    if (clientScore === 10 && value >= 150) {
        clientScore = 0;
        console.log("=====================")
        console.log(`10 scores! Desconto de 25%`)
        console.log(`Scores: ${clientScore}`)
        console.log(`De: R$${value} por R$${valueOff}`)
        console.log("=====================")
        console.log()
    }
})
```

esse é o meu arquivo .json antes desta parte do código ser executada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
preciso sobrescrever o "score": 0 para "score": 1

e é assim que ele fica depois que essa parte do código é executada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ps.: no começo do código tem command(client, 'test_pay', (message) => { °codigo° }, além de Node.JS, estou usando Discord.JS, algumas coisas desse código são do próprio Discord.JS, como o *message.content*, que pega o conteúdo da string, e faz um replace de:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

para

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

O método `fs.writefile()` substitui o arquivo toda vez em que o método for chamado, se ele não existir vai ser criado o arquivo com o conteúdo que você colocar, se existir ele vai substituir, portanto, você deve usar o método `fs.appendFile()` caso seu arquivo não exista ele vai criar e adicionar o conteúdo, caso ele existir ele vai adicionar sem substituir nada. Este é um exemplo mais é só adaptar para o seu:

```
const fs = require('fs');                                     
constt file = __dirname + '/teste.json';

const produto = {
 nome: 'Smartphone',
 preco: 1749.99,
 desconto: 0.15
};                                                              
fs.appendFile('mynewfile2.txt', JSON.stringify(produto), err => {
 console.log(err || 'Arquivo salvo');
});
```

Agora de um jeito que não vai invalidar a sintaxe do json

```
const { readFile, writeFile } = require('fs').promises;                                                              
async function addClient(filename, clientData) {                
// Lê o arquivo e obtem o array atual:
const data = await readFile(filename, 'utf-8');
const json = JSON.parse(data || '[]');
                                                           
if (!Array.isArray(json)) {                                     
 throw new Error(`Malformed JSON. Expected array, got: ${json}.`);
}
                                                            
// Note que mutamos o JSON diretamente para "adicionar o cliente", uma vez que                                              
// sobre-escreveremos o arquivo com o novo conteúdo (modificado).
json.push(clientData);
                               
// Transformamos o JSON modificado em string para sobre-escrever no arquivo:
const jsonString = JSON.stringify(json);                                                                                    
// Modificamos o arquivo:
await writeFile(filename, jsonString);                     
}
                                                          
// Posso chamar quantas vezes for necessário, a estrutura sintática do JSON
// irá se manter válida.
addClient('mynewFile2.txt', {
 name: 'Bob',
 age: 10
})
.then(() => console.log('OK.'))
.catch(console.error);
```

Desta forma o array fica dentro de um objeto, é uma boa prática fazer desta forma, não modifiquei muito o arquivo que o colega abaixo deu mais o importante é o resultado, tem umas pergunta aqui no stack overflow mesmo pra deixar o array do primeiro exemplo igual ao segundo, sem mudar tanto o códico, tem uma pergunta aqui no stack overflow caso você quiser deixar o primeiro exemplo igual ao segundo sem muitas mudanças da uma olhada.
Tá aí a resposta, vlw! :)

Comment: Com todo respeito, mas append “bruto” em JSON não me parece muito válido, uma vez que a partir do primeiro append a estrutura sintática do JSON já terá sido invalidada.

Comment: É só um exemplo, mas porque não é muito válido?

Comment: Imagine que você tem um JSON em que o primeiro nível é um objeto (mas também se tornaria inválido em caso de array). Algo como: `{ ... }`. Até aí, está válido. Mas imagine que um append é feito no arquivo, aí teremos algo como: `{ ... } { ... }`. Percebe o problema? A partir do primeiro append se invalida a estrutura sintática do JSON, o que impediria o parse para o próximo uso.

Comment: A resposta está boa, só esse detalhe que foi problemático. Uma coisa que pode fazer é: ao ler o arquivo, realiza-se o parse (`JSON.parse`). Faz-se as modificações no objeto e, por fim, transforma-o em uma string JSON (`JSON.stringify`). Aí você pode sobre-escrever todo o conteúdo do arquivo pela string (em formato JSON) referente aos novos dados. Aí não tem o problema da invalidação sintática. Se você quiser editar a resposta para corrigir aquele problema, ficarei feliz em dar o +1. :-)

Comment: Sim, entendi o que você quis dizer, entendi o problema da solução que apontei, porém não entendi a solução que você propôs muito bem, tentei aplicar +- pelo que entendi mais não deu muito certo poderia me explicar melhor kkk, desculpe.

Comment: Pode fazer algo mais ou menos [assim](https://github.com/lffg2/sopt/blob/main/snippets/comment916460_493186/1.mjs).

Comment: Sim, vou fazer isso que você disse porém postei uma pergunta aqui no stack overflow sobre isso, quero saber se tem uma maneira de fazer isto que você disse sem mudar muita coisa no códico, porque até tem algumas soluções porém muda muita coisa, quero saber se é possível mudar o menos possível pq também uso o append file em algumas situações e gostaria de saber se é possível fazer isto.

Comment: Editado hehe :)

Answer (score -1):

Fala, cara, beleza ?

Seguinte, você realmente precisar ler esse arquivo json com a lib fs ?

Você pode apenas importar o arquivo com o (require)

Dessa forma você terá o json já formatado no data e não precisa do parse.

Mas da forma que você fez vai funcionar também, só que tem que fazer o parse depois como você fez.

Depois você precisa setar os valores que você quer modificar, com o "document.clients[clientId].score = novo score"

Por exemplo :

```
const data = require('test.json');

command(client, 'test_pay', (message) => {  
    var cont = message.content.replace('%test_pay', '').split(' ')
    var value = cont[0]
    var clientId = cont[1] - 1
    var clientScore = 9 //data.clients[clientId].score
    var client = data.clients[clientId].nome
    var valueOff = value - ((value * 25) / 100)

    if (value >= 150) {
        clientScore += 1;
        // você precisa setar o novo valor no objeto "score" antes de salvar 
        // ele no arquivo

        data.clients[clientId].score = clientScore;

        var data = JSON.stringify(clientScore, null, 2)
        fs.writeFile('test.json', data, finished)
        function finished(err) {
            console.log('all set.')
        }
        console.log("=====================")
        console.log(`Mensagem: ${message.content}`)
        console.log(`Valor: ${value}`)
        console.log(`Id do Cliente: ${clientId}`)
        console.log("=====================")
        console.log(`Cliente: ${client}`)
        console.log(`Valor pago: R$${value}`)
        console.log(`Score: ${clientScore}`)
        console.log("=====================")
        console.log()
    } else {
        console.log("=====================")
        console.log(`Mensagem: ${message.content}`)
        console.log(`Valor: ${value}`)
        console.log(`Id do Cliente: ${clientId}`)
        console.log("=====================")
        console.log(`Cliente: ${client}`)
        console.log(`Valor pago: R$${value}`)
        console.log(`Score: ${clientScore}`)
        console.log("=====================")
        console.log()
    }

    if (clientScore === 10 && value >= 150) {
        clientScore = 0;
        console.log("=====================")
        console.log(`10 scores! Desconto de 25%`)
        console.log(`Scores: ${clientScore}`)
        console.log(`De: R$${value} por R$${valueOff}`)
        console.log("=====================")
        console.log()
    }
})
```