# Como não repetir informações em um arquivo node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Galera tenho esse códico:

```
const fs = require('fs');                                     
const produto = {
 nome: 'Smartphone',
 preco: 1749.99,                                               
 descontoo: 0.15
}                                                             
fs.appendFile('mynewfile2.txt', 
 JSON.stringify(produto), err => {                                                            
  console.log(err || 'Arquivo salvo');
});
```

Percebam que cada vez que eu rodar o códico ele vai repetir a informação, porém eu quero que não repita informações iguais, porém quero atingir esse resultado de maneira simples sem mudar muita coisa no códico se possível. É que estava respondendo uma pessoa aqui no stack overflow e dei essa resposta e um comentário me fez ver este problema, porém eu uso o `appendFile` e gostaria de saber se tem alguma maneira de fazer isso sem precisar quase que reescrever todo o códico

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "repetir informações"? Salvar sempre os mesmos dados?

Comment: Sim, era essa pergunta que estava me referindo que estava fazendo, gostaria de saber se tem como não repetir dados (ou informações duplicatas) sem precisar mudar muito o códico, como naquele exemplo que você apontou em outra pergunta.

Comment: É que uso o `appendFile` bastante ... E isso me deixou deverás curiosos kk.

Comment: Você chegou a olhar o código que eu postei como comentário na sua [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/493186/69296)? Veja-o novamente **[aqui](https://github.com/lffg2/sopt/blob/main/snippets/comment916460_493186/1.mjs)**. Note que ele não substitui os dados, apenas _adiciona_ um novo elemento ao final do array... Substituir o conteúdo do arquivo (por um novo, incrementado) é diferente de substituir as informações.

Comment: Eu tentei rodar mais me retornou um erro no import, e mesmo que eu use require para importar os módulos etc, mais ele me retorna outro erro em `JSON.parse(data?.trim() | | '[]')` não consegui executar o códico para entender melhor, por isso fiz a outra pergunta.

Comment: Deve ser minha versão do node js creio eu

Comment: [Tente este.](https://github.com/lffg2/sopt/blob/main/snippets/comment916460_493186/2.js)

Comment: Esse deu certo hehe vou editar a resposta, tinha entendido outra coisa kkk fiquei um tempão tentando resolver aquilo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é não utilizar o `appendFile`.

Utilizando o seu código, basta modificar o `appendFile` para a função `writeFile`

Segue um exemplo:

```
const fs = require('fs');
let data = null
try {
    data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./mynewfile2.txt'))
} catch (e) {
    console.log('não foi possível ler o arquivo.')
}

const produto = {
 nome: 'Smartphone',
 preco: 1749.99,
 descontoo: 0.15
}
const produtos = data || []
produtos.push(produto)
fs.writeFile('mynewfile2.txt', JSON.stringify(produtos), err => {
  console.log(err || 'Arquivo salvo');
});
```

Repare que no código apenas troquei o nome da função utilizada do módulo `fs`. Segue a [documentação](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)

Ao utilizar a função `appendFile` você está sempre escrevendo dados ao final do arquivo. Ao utilizar o writeFile estamos escrevendo por cima das informações gravadas anteriormente.

Neste código estamos utilizando o `try catch` apenas para garantir a execução do código com sucesso quando o arquivo não existe.

Usando esta lógica repare que cada vez que executamos o código estamos adicionando uma nova entidade ao array de produtos.

Comment: Sim resolveria o problema, só que eu gostaria de não substituir informações que já estão lá saca? O `appendFile` não substitui, se eu usar o `writeFile` ele vai substituir todo o arquivo mesmo que as informações que estão lá não seja repetidas.

Comment: Agora entendi o requisito, segue a correção.